# Nested array matching

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How can I match an object in a nested array?

Here is an example object:

```
_id: "something", array: [[], [{id: "test"}], []]
```

To match this, I've tried `array.$.id: "test"`, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you actually meant as a valid structure:

```js
{ "_id" : "array" : [ [ ], [ { "_id" : "test" } ], [ ] ] }
```

In which to find the matching document you use:

```
db.test.find({ "array": { "$elemMatch": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": "test" } } } })
```

I hope that is supported correctly in minimongo, but that is the correct server side for MongoDB syntax anyhow.

Just as a side note, MongoDB versions prior to 2.6 might allow this to work:

```
db.test.find({ "array": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": "test" } }  })
```

But it shouldn't as this is a bug but is fixed in 2.6. Due to be documented [DOCS-3434](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-3434)

Comment: I didn't mean the document's array by _id, sorry, I guess that's a bad example. You can consider it to just be a element in the subobject. I updated the question.

Comment: Actually I think your answer still holds.

Comment: @ChristianStewart `.find()` only matches documents. You can project to show just the element that matched, but not with nested arrays as the matching index will be that of the "outer" array. If you need just th matching element or the array use the aggregation framework instead.